# Add PHP API documentation to vims balloonexpr

Tags: php, vim, documentation

Vim has [balloonexpr](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27balloonexpr%27), which is leveraged in e.g. [Ruby](https://github.com/vim-ruby/vim-ruby/blob/master/ftplugin/ruby.vim#L53) to show the API documentation for current hovered word.

How could I get something similar for PHP? What CLI/programmable options are there to access the PHP API documentation? Obviously an offline version is preferred over the online php.net HTML version :). Could e.g. doxygen be used for this?

Are there projects already that allow tooltips with PHP API documentation?

Answer (score 3):

> The manual is also available via *nix style man pages. To install and use:
>
> Install: `pear install doc.php.net/pman`
>
> Upgrade: `pear upgrade doc.php.net/pman`
>
> Example usage: `pman strlen`

<sup>(From: http://php.net/download-docs.php)</sup>

Once you have the `pman` pages installed, you could write a little `balloonexpr` function to get whatever information you need.

There are also SQLite and JSON documentation sources which might contain the information you want to display, at http://doc.php.net/downloads/

Comment: Thanks. I've turned these into a very rough initial [ftplugin](https://github.com/berkes/vim-pman).

Answer (score 2):

It's using the `ri` CLI utility. Does such a program exist for PHP?

**EDIT**

Yes, more or less. Here are a few links:

- [`phpm`](http://web.archive.org/web/20041206211514/phpvolcano.com/articles/manual/index.php)
- [`php --rf function_name`](http://php.net/manual/bg/features.commandline.php)
- [`phpm 2.0`](http://www.sitepoint.com/php-manual-cli-style-20/)

Note that I just discovered them myself.

Comment: For now, I went with pman, since phpm and phpm 2.0 appear abandoned and old. php -rf functionname is new to me and seems very promising. I will check that out later.