# adding native php function to ctags for vim

Tags: php, vim, ctags

so i can build a set of tags using ctags and when i type out the function and hit the open parenthesis in the call, a little bar pops up that shows the parameters. the problem is that it doesn't show up for any native functions, only those declared in my project directory.

is there a list of tags somewhere or a way i can get native php functions to parameter hint for me the same way? so when i do something like strstr( it would pop up:

```
strstr(string $haystack , mixed $needle [, bool $before_needle = false ])
```

Answer (score 1):

Using only basic omni-completion, I get a long list of possible completions when I type `str<C-x><C-o>`. This is the content of the preview window when I select `strstr(`:

```
strstr(string haystack, string needle | string
```

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8954659/546861) forother ideas.